# Microsoft SQL - Stored Procedure to transfer an employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that transfers an employee from the current team to another team. So far I've done this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC pr_EmployeeTeam @IDTeam1 int, @IDTeam2 int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NIC int
    SELECT @IDTeam1 = IDTeam from StuffTeams
    SELECT @IDTeam2 = IDTeam from StuffTeams

    UPDATE StuffTeams SET IDTeam = @IDTeam1 WHERE NIC = @NIC
    UPDATE StuffTeams SET IDTeam = @IDTeam2 WHERE NIC = @NIC 
END

EXEC pr_EmployeeTeam 2,5
```

And my `StuffTeam` table:

```
CREATE TABLE StuffTeams(
    IDStuffTeam nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    IDTeam int NOT NULL,
    NIC int NOT NULL,
    DateStart date NOT NULL,
    DateFinish date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Stuff PRIMARY KEY (IDStuffTeam),
    CONSTRAINT FK_sTeam FOREIGN KEY (IDTeam) REFERENCES Teams (IDTeam),
    CONSTRAINT FK_sNIC FOREIGN KEY (NIC) REFERENCES Employees (NIC),
)
```

Inside of `StuffTeams` I have 30 values but when I exec the code says

> 0 rows affacted

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE PROC sp_UpdateTeam
    @TeamID int,
    @NIC int
AS
BEGIN
    update StuffTeams SET IDTeam = @TeamID
    WHERE NIC = @NIC
END

EXEC sp_UpdateTeam 5,54321
```

This solved my problem! Thanks

Comment: You never assign `@NIC` a value and `NULL` matches no rows.

Comment: And you overwrite the input parameters `@IDTeam1`, `@IDTeam2` with some unpredictable value (which will likely be the same for both variables)

Comment: So, sp needs to receive `@IDTeam1`, `@IDTeam2` and also `@NIC`? When I add `@NIC` into sp again, I executed as `EXEC sp_EmployeeTeam 2,5,12345`. This time 6 rows affected

Comment: You overwirthe the input parameters, you assign the same value to both variables, you update the table twice with the same value... all in all this code doesn't make much sense. Please provide sample data and the expected result (how many rows updated and so on) - otherwise it is not possible to support you here.

Comment: Imagine that I have a `IDTeam = 1` which is Green Team and `IDTeam = 2` which is Yellow Team. I want to receive `NIC` number of Employee which is like a ID Number for them and change from Green Team to Yellow Team.

Comment: Surely a team has more than one employee though, @dtaskin, otherwise what is the point in having a "team"?

Comment: `SELECT @IDTeam1 = IDTeam from StuffTeams` should have a WHERE clause, no? Do you even need that SELECT, for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Based upon your requirement, I have updated your proc as shown below:`

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC pr_EmployeeTeam @IDTeam1 int, @IDTeam2 int  
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @NIC int
SELECT @NIC = IDTeam from StuffTeams WHERE IDTeam = @IDTeam1    
UPDATE StuffTeams SET IDTeam = @IDTeam2 WHERE NIC = @NIC

END
```

EXEC pr_EmployeeTeam 2,5